# Setting up a TYPO3 page as multilingual page

Tags: typo3

I've got a TYPO3 page which is only in german. Now I want to set up the page in english as well. How can I realise this? I've read about webpage language and so on but, can't find a whole tutorial.

I'm using TYPO3 6.2.9

Thanks a lot

Update

```
## Localization menu:
lib.langMenu = HMENU
lib.langMenu {
    special = language
    special.value = 0,1,2
    special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
    1 = GMENU
    1.NO {
            XY = [5.w]+4, [5.h]+4
            backColor = white
            5 = IMAGE
            5.file = EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_uk.gif  || EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_de.gif
            5.offset = 2,2
    }

    1.ACT < lib.langMenu.1.NO
    1.ACT=1
    1.ACT.backColor = black

    1.USERDEF1 < lib.langMenu.1.NO
    1.USERDEF1=1
    1.USERDEF1.5.file = EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_uk.gif  || EXT:cms/tslib/media/flags/flag_de.gif
    1.USERDEF1.noLink = 0

    1.USERDEF2 < lib.langMenu.1.USERDEF1
    1.USERDEF2.backColor = green
}
```

Comment: Have you found the TYPO3 [frontend localization guide](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/)?

Comment: thanks, I read it but I cant find what here is explained ... https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FrontendLocalizationGuide/BasicSetupOfALocalizedWebsite/SettingUpLanguages/Index.html

Comment: Select the List-module and the root of the pagetree (id = 0). There you can add these records as usual.

Comment: First you need to add English lang-http://screencast.com/t/4xBjyj0HCut then you can add English content as well - http://screencast.com/t/eqwLfdneCX60 yes, you have to set lang menu on FE for switch lang

Comment: Thanks nice works fine. but the next step is to add the language switch in the for FE .. But dosn't work ... I've added the above code in typoscript but no switche appears

Comment: No Hint how to add the switcher in the view?

Comment: Have you added the menu to a placeholder or marker like that:

`page.10.marks.LANGMENU < lib.langMenu`

Then it will appear if you set ###LANGMENU### somewhere in your template

Comment: EXT:cms has been removed from later core versions, so watchout the path!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

in TYPO3 it is really easy to set up an other Language

All you need to do ist:

Create on your rootpage (the world) a new lanuguage
Then add in your Setup on the rootpage the following (for example french)

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = fr
config.locale_all = fr_FR
[global]
```

Then translate your first page.

You can access the page  with [this link](http://www.yourpage.de/index.php?id=XXyourtranslatedpageidXX&L=1).

Hope it helps.